# HTML/Javascript - show DIV if date falls within a start/end date?

Tags: javascript, html, show, show-hide

I'm working on a small personal project where if I enter a date a single or more divs show (if the date falls within several divs date ranges aka start/end)

For example if I set two exams:

- Exam 1 - between 05/05/2014 - 20/08/2014
- Exam 2 - between 10/05/2014 - 20/08/2014

If I enter the date say 15/05/2014 - this should display both divs that would for example contain study guides etc...

Here is my code so far: **http://jsfiddle.net/oab1kfad/**

```
<br/>Enter date you want to check(dd/mm/yyyy):
<input type="text" name="cDate" id="cDate" />
<input type="submit" value="Check" onclick="dateCheck();" />
<div id="Test1" style="display: none">
     <h3>           
         <input alt="Expand Section" onclick="Showhide('showhide_Test1')" /> Header test
     </h3>

    <div id="showhide_Test1" style="display: none">
        <div style="background-color: #C0F2EC"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
var DOP_DATES = [ //div id      //start       //end
["Test1", "04/04/2013", "08/10/2015"],
    ["Test2", "12/12/2014", "01/03/2016"]

];
var NUM_DOP = 2;

function dateCheck() {

    var cDate;

    cDate = Date.parse(document.getElementById("cDate").value);

    var divID = DOP_DATES[i][0];
    var startDateArr = DOP_DATES[i][1].split("/");
    var endDateArr = DOP_DATES[i][2].split("/");
    var elem = document.getElementById(divID);
    var today = new Date();


    startDateArr[1]--;
    endDateArr[1]--;

    var startDate = cDate(startDateArr[2], startDateArr[1], startDateArr[0], 0, 0, 0, 0);
    var endDate = cDate(endDateArr[2], endDateArr[1], endDateArr[0], 0, 0, 0, 0);

    if ((cDate <= endDateArr && cDate >= startDateArr)) Show(elem);

}

function Show(elem) {
    elem.style.display = "block";
}

function Hide(elem) {
    elem.style.display = "none";
}

function Showhide(divID) {
    var elem = document.getElementById(divID);

    if (elem.style.display == "none") {
        Show(elem);
    } else {
        Hide(elem);
    }
}
```

As you can see no Javascrip error codes are thrown. I assume that I'm lacking an array type function once it detects a date falls between the two dates?

Comment: Put the relevant code as part of your question, please.

Comment: I think you misinterpret the guidance that links to jsfiddle.net must be accompanied by code.  It's not saying the actual link should be indented and accompanied with the word "Code". It's saying that the source code (or preferably just the relevant snippets) used within the fiddle should also be placed in the question, indented by 4 spaces so that it is properly formatted as `code`.

Comment: @drs Code from the fiddle has been added to the question.

Comment: where is used `NUM_DOP` + 
what is `i` in `var divID = DOP_DATES[i][0];` ?  Are you sure you have no error thrown? I've got a lot when trying to resolve the firsts…

Comment: @Kaiido According to jsfiddle no errors exist - so I assume there is no error? granted logic would say if it doesn't work there's a error.

Comment: It is because no code is executed. WHhen you submit a date, console throws `ReferenceError: dateCheck is not defined` on jsFiddle and  `ReferenceError: i is not defined
 

var divID = DOP_DATES[i][0];` on external html file